# Dojo Example Web Applications that show standards / quality?

Tags: eclipse, dojo, aptana

just starting to learn Dojo, and I am having a heck of a time finding some good examples to look at or even a good IDE installation guide (currently using a plugin of Aptana in Eclipse).

I'd love to look an app (with some instruction on how to set it up) that demonstrates some of Dojo Standards of developing a Large Scale Dojo Application (utilizing Modules, OOP, etc.)

Its hard for me to get started without examples / understanding some of dojo's higher level concepts.

---

Edit** 
 [Found this link](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2009/jw-01-introduction-to-dojo-1.html) from javaworld... I though it was a good start... if anyone has any other tutorials like this (esp for incorporating AJAX / JSON into Dojo) I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists a lot of Tutorials and documentation on the main page:

- [Tutorials](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/)
- [Reference Guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/)
- [API Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/)

I think the best way is to pick the Tutorials and just work through them. I would start with the basic, finding some DOM elements, AJAX, animation and so on. If you knew the basics work through the tutorials that explains how you can create your own Widgets.

To order it a little bit. Read the other tutorials not linked here before to get warm with Dojo.

- [Learn OOP in Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/declare/)
- [Understand the Base Class every widget inherit from](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/understanding_widget/)
- [Create your own Widget](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/recipes/custom_widget/)
- [GUI Design with Dijit Layout](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dijit_layout/)
- [How to build a large application](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/recipes/app_controller/)
- [Deploy your application](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/build/)

Another good help is to use the maillinglist. There also exists a webgui to the mailinglist with the possibility to send messages from there.

http://dojotoolkit.org/community/

If you need professional Support look at http://www.sitepen.com/